# How to type superscript in iMovie?

Tags: imovie, text

I want to type superscript in iMovie to indicate a large number (like 10^50). I don't know how to do this if there's a way, so can someone please help? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried typing it in Pages, Textpad, or Word and then pasting it into iMovie?

Comment: No...but I found the solution: to insert special characters (cmd + ctrl + space) and add superscript characters.